# Checking commit message in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I wonder if it is possible in TortoisHG, like in TortoiseSVN, to check if a commit message includes an issue id?
In TortoiseSVN you could set the bugtraq properties on the repo to make a dialog box pop up and warn if an id was not included, and I am looking for a way to do the same thing (still need it to be possible to check in, just show a warning that id is not included and be able to abort the commit if you want to).

Thanks in advance
Jonas H.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, nothing like that is possible directly in TortoiseHG.
But TortoiseHG is only a GUI for Mercurial, and in Mercurial, you can do stuff like that with hooks.

See chapter 10 in the [HG book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) for a general desription of what hooks are and how they work:
[Handling repository events with hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)

There is even a specific example in this chapter [that rolls back a commit if it doesn't contain a bug id](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#x_21d).

Comment: You are probably correct. I ended up using a hook, showing a dialog box via vbscript that allows one to select wether to continue or not with the commit, which was the ting I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog in TortoiseHg 2.4's settings looks like what you want:

[image]

Comment: Close, but I need to be able to commit even if no issue ID. Just need to get a warning so I can abort the commit if I need to (forgot to add ID in commit msg), or continue with the commit (no related ID). A hook takes care of that now, but would be nice if TortoiseHG included that funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

I only know about the setting `issue.linkmandatory = True` which forces entry of an issue reference specified in `issue.regex` and `issue.link` on every commit.